# Is there a way for vba to distribute values within evenly?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array of (5,6) in a spreadsheet and it can contain random values between 0 and 15. I'm creating a VBA script that according to the general average of the matrix will concentrate or distribute the values according to the result of the general average.

This is for a inventory system of clothes store. The rows on the array mean the size (of the inventory, L, M, S, xS, xL, xxL) and the columns the different stores.

```
Private Sub Trasladeichon(concentrado, ref, rBogota, cuenta)

    Dim talla As String
    Dim cantidad As Integer

    tiendas = concentrado
    Set posicion = ActiveCell
    Set rooty = posicion
    profundidad = cuenta

    talla = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    'rBogota.Select

    For p = 0 To profundidad - 1
       producto = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rBogota)

            For i = 0 To tiendas - 1
                cantidad = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(producto / tiendas, 2)
                If ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value < cantidad Then
                    For j = 5 To i Step -1 ' CAMBIAR 5 POR NUMERO DE TIENDAS
                        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).Value > 0 Then
                            Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value < cantidad And ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).Value > 0 And ActiveCell.Offset(0, j) <> ActiveCell.Offset(0, i)
                                ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value + 1
                                ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).Value - 1


                            Loop

                            If ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = cantidad Then
                                   GoTo iloop
                           End If
                        End If

                    Next j
                End If


iloop:
            Next i
                   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            For i = 0 To tiendas - 1
                If ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value > cantidad Then
                    For j = i To tiendas - 1
                             Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value > cantidad And ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).Value < cantidad And ActiveCell.Offset(0, j) <> ActiveCell.Offset(0, i)
                                ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(o, i).Value - 1
                                  ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(o, j).Value + 1
                            Loop
                    Next j
                End If
            Next i

       '''''''''''''''''''''''




            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next p
End Sub
```

Here's an example with single lines of the matrix with different values inside:

> [0][0][0][2][0] -> [2][0][0][0][0] If there is a low quantity ov values inside the matrix, put all values in (0,0)
>
> [0][0][1][2][0] -> [2][1][][][] Here we have a low quantity of inventory but is engouh to be distributed in two stores so it distributes to the first stores in the left.
>
> [0][1][0][1][1] -> Same case scenario as the previous one
>
> [0][0][0][10][0] -> [2][2][2][2][2] enough inventory to sort into all stores.
>
> [0][5][0][5][0] -> [2][2][2][2][2] sames as before.

Comment: Need a little bit more info for your specific question (like if cell is 0 or what?), but yes, that is possible.  `If ConditionA AND ConditionB Then` would allow for multiple criterion to be applied in the same if-statement.

Comment: You need to be more careful with your code; as is, it does not even compile. Sometimes you seem to use `#` and sometimes `'` to mark comments. That `iloop` label is not defined. You don't finish the loops and the sub. Please [edit] your question and make sure you provide a [mcve].